# Cannot get .text Property of UITextField in Swift -- Error: "Instance member 'textFieldName' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uikit, xcode7

All I'm trying to do is get the text input from a UITextField object on my main.storyboard.  Both @IBOutlet objects show that they are linked to the correct text field objects.  However, when I try to make the constant meenieOneText take on the value of the .text property of the meenieOne UITextField, I get the error message "Instance member 'meenieOne' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'.

I'm really new at this so I could be doing something simple completely wrong, but I'm at my wit's end with this because it looks right to me.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var meenieOne: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var meenieTwo: UITextField!

    let meenieOneText: String = meenieOne.text
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
var meenieOneText: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  meenieOneText = meenieOne.text!
}
```

You have a problem, because in iOS the Storyboard elements, while accessible, may not have been initialised (eg. the user cannot see them) as you try to access their properties. The easiest way to ensure the elements are initialised, you would access them after viewDidLoad(). There are also other phases such as 'viewDidDisappear' and so forth. See Apple documentation on ViewControllers here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/

Comment: Thank you so much!  There are so many nuances to all of this.  So, if you don't mind, how would I initialize the text field without using the viewDidLoad method?

Comment: As far as I am aware, you cannot access the text field until after the view has loaded. The text just isn't there. If you have some important data that you need, it is considered better practice to save that data in a variable (eg. let text: String = "I should be in the text field") and then pass it in to the text field as the view loads. Maybe you could elaborate a bit more on your case so we could get more info on what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can not use properties of `UITextField` directly in class. Write same code in any function. Its work properly.